# Imported object from X3D not rendered

Tags: rendering

I have an object generated as a VTK file, then converted as X3D and imported in Blender which is visible but not rendered.

I tried different parameters, the object is visible and renderable but nothing shows while rendering.

What am I missing? What should I do to make those lines visible in the resulting rendering?

[image]

Comment: It is a bezier curve with no visible geometry. Without any bevel or extrusion there is nothing visible to render

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added the question about this: What should I do to make those lines visible in the resulting rendering?